# Pass in a string from txt file into pd.read.csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file of strings consisting of 2 rows 1 column in which I want to pass in the first row string into pd.read.csv

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('datainput.txt',  header=None)
data.columns = ["a"]
print(data.iloc[0])

df = pd.read_excel(data.iloc[0].astype('string'))
outT = data.iloc[1].astype('string')
```

.astype('string') does not work

Error:

```
 a  test.xlsx
 Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Desired Output

```
Simply pass in a string into pd.read.csv
```

Comment: What is the output of data.iloc[0]?

Comment: You cannot pass a `Series` object to the `read_excel` function - it is expecting a file

Comment: @Emi OB: I am reading in an exel file, the name of which is defined in txt file as name.xlsx

Comment: but i used astype to convert series to string

Comment: @user9106985 run just `data.iloc[0]`, and copy and paste the output here so we can see what it actually outpus (ideally added into your question)

Comment: No, that does not "convert" a series to string. It sets the `dtype` of your series to string (if it works, that is)

Comment: why do you want to use pandas to read a simple text file? cant you just read in the file as is and get the string?

Comment: I couldnt find an easy syntax to do it after some searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just read in the file as is?

```
from pathlib import Path
xl_path, outT = Path("data.txt").read_text().split("\n")
df = pd.read_excel(xl_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
df = pd.read_excel(data['a'].iloc[0])
```

If your DataFrame is natural number indexed, you can also use

```py
df = pd.read_excel(data.loc[0, 'a'])
```